# SSL on Devise not working properly Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, devise

I have got two methods in application_controller.rb

```
def force_ssl
      if !request.ssl?
        redirect_to :protocol => 'https'
      end
    end

    def no_ssl
      if request.ssl?
        redirect_to :protocol => "http"
      end
    end
```

also I have done `before_filter :no_ssl` in application.rb

Now I am trying to call force_ssl method in sessions controller of devise to secure login through SSL

In sessions_controller.rb file I have done `skip_before_filter :no_ssl and before_filter :force_ssl`

I am not able to login when I use this, however if I do not do `before_filter :no_ssl` in application_controller.rb it works fine.

Since I have got lot of controller I was trying to put `before_filter :no_ssl` in application.rb so that I do not have to call `before_filter :no_ssl` in all the controllers as it will not be DRY.

I have tried almost all the available resources and dont know why this is not working.

P.S :- This is working for my other controllers except for the devise controller
Any suggestions??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Bartt-SSL_Requirement, it works well in Rails 3.1, that way you don't need the before_filter and skip_before_filter. In BarttSSLRequirement you can use the "ssl_exceptions" for your before_filter needs.
2. SSL sometimes gives problems in Development, push it to staging and it should work.

Comment: yes when I tried it on staging it was working, though I was not using Bartt-SSL earlier, I will try it with Bartt-SSL